# How to rectify a TypeError in python?Beautiful Soup string to tag error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Here is simple snippet to scrape Wikipedia website and to print each of its contents separately like cast in separate variable and production in separate variable and so on ..
Here in the first div named "bodyContent" there is a another div names "mw-content-text" here my problem is retrieve the data of the first paragraphs before the tag "h2" and i have a code snippet to work out this and unable to convert from BeautifulSoup tag from string and the error is **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'str'**

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film)"
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext,"lxml")
#print soup.prettify()
movie_title = soup.find('h1',{'id':'firstHeading'})
print movie_title.text
movie_info = soup.find_all('p')
#print movie_info[0].text 
#print movie_info[1].text
'''I dont want like this because we dont know how many
 intro paragraphs will be so we have to scrape all paras just before that h2 tag'''
```

Here the problem rises i want to iterate and add .next_sibling and to make a try-exception block to find if the

> "resultant_next_url.name == 'p' "

```
def findNextSibling(base_url):
    tag_addition = 'next_sibling'
    next_url = base_url+'.'+tag_addition
    return next_url
```

And finally to do like this

```
base_url = movie_info[0]
resultant_url = findNextSibling(base_url)
print resultant_url.text
```

Comment: Why do you add a string to a tag?

Comment: I dont want to i just want to loop like this movie_info[0] with .next_sibling attached to it each time and print text inside it till a h2 tag occurs

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Do you mean `return base_url.next_sibling`? Or you just want `resultant_url = base_url.next_sibling`?

Comment: Yaa return base_url.next_sibling but when we call it again it should return movie_info[0].next_sibling.next_sibling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found answer, this is solving the problem

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film)"
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext,"lxml")
#print soup.prettify()
movie_title = soup.find('h1',{'id':'firstHeading'})
print movie_title.text

movie_info = soup.find_all('p')
# print movie_info[0].text
# print movie_info[1].text

def findNextSibling(resultant_url):
    #tag_addition = 'next_sibling'
    #base_url.string = base_url.string + '.' + tag_addition
    return resultant_url.next_sibling

resultant_url = movie_info[0]
resultant_url = findNextSibling(resultant_url)
print resultant_url.text
```